# "TypeError: Cannot create initializer for non-floating point type." when using extract features in tf-slim with VGG19 model

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tf-slim

I want to extract features from the pool5 layer from vgg19. I am using tf-slim library for that . I get a very weird error saying

```
TypeError: Cannot create initializer for non-floating point type.
```

My images are ndarrays of dtype=uint8 . So in order to fix this error I changed my images to float using    `tf.to_float(images)` . But now it complains that my gpu is out of memory which is very weird. Because I have a nvidia GeForce GTX 1080 Ti with 11gb vram and there are no other processes running on it. The batch size is just 2000 images. Before switching to tf-slim I was using caffe and this batch size was not a problem at all.
My code is like:

```
                with slim.arg_scope(vgg.vgg_arg_scope()):
                _, end_points = vgg.vgg_19(tf.to_float(images), num_classes=1000,is_training=False)
            init_fn = slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(
                os.path.join(checkpoints_dir, 'vgg_19.ckpt'),
                slim.get_model_variables('vgg_19'))
            features = end_points['vgg_19/pool5']
```

So as you see above I am just trying to extract features from the pool5 layer from the pretrained weights. So what is the problem here? Is converting to float a problem? As I said before I was using caffe for this and I was able to extract features from even 20,000 images and here it's just 2000.The error in particular says:

```
ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[2000,224,224,64]
 [[Node: vgg_19/conv1/conv1_1/convolution = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](ToFloat, vgg_19/conv1/conv1_1/weights/read)]]
 [[Node: vgg_19/pool5/MaxPool/_77 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_154_vgg_19/pool5/MaxPool", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Note: the shape of image variable is [2000,224,224,3]

Thanks

Comment: your `batch_size` is too high for the `gpu` you are using. the erros suggest `gpu` memory allocation problem. try `batch_size` 32 or 64.

Comment: I don't think so. 4*2000*224*224*3 bytes is just 1 gb of vram. And as I mentioned in my post I was able to extract features from 20,000 images using caffe. But I am not sure if there is any difference between how caffe and tf-slim work. Are you aware if tf.slim requires substantially more memory than caffe for feature extraction?

Comment: @HIMANSHURAI You are not considering all intermediate variables that are used in a forward/backward pass, your batch size is too large.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro . So this implies that Caffe is much better opimized than tf-slim? I was using caffe for feature extraction before and then processing those features using tensorflow. But then I wanted to use tf end-to-end so tried switching to tf-slim. But it seems it's not ideal for big batch sizes and not as optimized as caffe

Comment: @HIMANSHURAI No, I don't think you can use a batch size of 2000 images with Caffe either. Its not a software but a conceptual problem given the amount of RAM you have.

Comment: @HIMANSHURAI By the way, to process 2000 images, you do not need to set the batch size to 2000, you can set it lower so less images are processed *at the same time*, but then TF will iterate over the dataset so all images are processed.

Comment: Except that I did! And please do note that there is no backpropagation here. I am not finetuning my nets . Just doing forward propagation to extract features from a pool layer . It hardly takes around 30 seconds for my caffe code to extract features from these 2000 images

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I have 20000 images and I form batches of size 2000 and process these.

Comment: @HIMANSHURAI Saying "I did it" proves nothing, there is probably something you are overlooking. But anyways, the solution here is to use a smaller batch size.